# What is the time complexity of this C++ function?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have written a function to show both number who is prime and factor of a specific number n.

```
bool PrimeFactor(int n){
    int count = 0;// count divisors

    for (int i = 2 ; i < n; i++){
        if ( n % i == 0 ){
            if ( PrimeFactor(i)){              
                cout << i << endl;
            }
            count ++;
        }
    }

    if (count > 0)//not prime
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The result may be duplicated in some place, but that's not the big matter. I don't know how to calculate the time complexity of this recursive func .

Comment: Depends on what `PrimeFactor` does.

Comment: Why is this function recursive? (btw, I wrapped your code to be a function named `PrimeFactor` because you said it was recursive. I hope I got that right.)

Comment: Also, note that this function would return `true` for 0 and 1, both of which are not prime.

Comment: How does it ever terminate?

If `PrimeFactor(2)` is called, then `2 % 2` is zero so it'll just keep looping?

Comment: @silentbang: Try drawing a tree with each function call as a node. Then try to figure out the mathematical function/relation that ties the number of nodes with n.

Comment: @Jeff: No, the loop condition wouldn't be met on the first iteration.

Comment: ah. I forgot to test with 0,1,2. This also doesn't work with prime n like when inputting 5, 7. How to solve the latter probl?

Comment: There's no point testing `PrimeFactor(i)`. The smallest proper factor of `n` is guaranteed to be prime, so just divide by that and keep looking for factors of `n / i` - that way all the factors you find will be prime, and whatever number you fail to find a factor of will also be prime. It does change how many repeats you get of each prime in the output, though, if that's important...

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a more extended version of Ben Voigt answer.

As Ben Voigt said, the version without the conditional is `O(n)`, this should be straightforward.

Now, the version with the conditional will execute the recursion inside the `if` statement a number of times equal to the number of divisors of n (= [value of the divisor function for n](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) = `d(n)`).

The lower limit `inf d(n) = 2`, since for every prime, this will be true and there are infinitely many primes, so no matter how big you make `n`, you can always find one for which `d(n) = 2`. This means that for primes, your function will recurse 0 times and it has complexity `O(n)`.

The upper limit is more complicated (and I need coffee), so lets skip that for a moment and calculate the average complexity. The average complexity of `d(n) = O(log n)`, so, as stated by Ben Voigt, the original function will have an average complexity of `O(n log n loglog n ...)`. More in detail: you have the for loop, which is `O(n)`, in this for loop you will recurse an average of `d(n) = O(log n)` times. Now you enter the function again and recurse `O(log (log n))` times, etc, etc.

Also note the comments to your question by DarkDust & Jeff Forster. It will not function the way you want it too. Furthermore, checking if even numbers divide `n` is useless, since even numbers will never be primes (except for 2 of course). Due to the recursion, you will enter the inner `if` (the one with `cout`) during recursive calls, so the output you get, will not be what you want (which I'm assuming is the distinct prime divisors of n).

Another way to save time is by only testing up to `floor(sqrt(n))`. If a number `i` divides `n` exactly, check if the quotient `j = n / i` is also a prime number. E.g. for `n = 6`, you'd test up to `floor(sqrt(6)) = 2`. Then you find that `i = 2` is a divisor and you check `j = 6 / 2 = 3`. You find that both `i` and `j` are prime divisors in this case.

Comment: Great explanation.  I didn't know about the "divisor function", I was just guessing (with a little bit of hand waving that factors multiply together to give the number).  It's nice that my estimate turns out to be right.  Of course, it's still possible (maybe even probable) that the divisor function of a number isn't independent of the divisor function values of the divisors, so the multiplication isn't strictly correct.  But it should still be the right complexity.

Comment: thks. So can the complexity get close to n^2 ?

Comment: @silentbang I guess so, don't take my word for it though. I've been searching for the complexity of ``lim sup d(n)``, but can't find it anywhere. Then again, I'm not a mathematician, so I might be searching for the wrong things. Or maybe it's right in front of me and I don't see it. Maybe try asking on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @silentbang Here, asked it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34501/complexity-of-divisor-function.

Answer (score 2):

This simplification will recurse no fewer times than the original, and it has complexity `O(n!)`.  So that's an upper bound.

```
bool PrimeFactor(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2 ; i < n; i++) PrimeFactor(i);
}
```

I think the complexity of the original is `O(n log n loglog n ...)`.

Comment: could the original be O(n!) ? can you explain your ans

Comment: The order of growth has to be specified; it can't be a recursive infinite one. Moreoever, I the order of growth is 2^n, it can't be n log n ... Probing the algorithm (the one in your response) I obtained the following: when n = 5, number of calls is 8; when n = 10, number of calls is 256; when n = 20, number of calls is 262144. Could you notice how exponential it is?

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi: My claim is that the order of the version in the question is *less than* the version in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to translate (to a recurrence relation) and solve your algorithm in a formal way, like the following:

[image]

The order of growth is **non polynomial**, which is an algorithm to avoid!

Comment: Looks like a mistake in the step where the sums disappear... I guess you have cancelled most of the terms, but `f(n-1, i)` is not the same as `f(n, i)` so the cancellation is incorrect.  (You have an additional error in the last step which doesn't affect the complexity, but the first error does)

Comment: Also, your definition of `f` is backwards.